# C: String Variable Loses Value After Returning From Void Function

Tags: c, variable-assignment, void, abstract-data-type, char-pointer

hope you are well.

I recently started learning ADT (Abstract Data Type) in college, and I have an assignment that states the following:

> Complete ADTDate adding the following primitive function:
>
> void dayWeekStr(DatePtr date,char *buffer)// places the day of the week of the date in buffer

So in `main()` you define a char pointer, and send it to the function alongside the date `struct`. Basically what the function does is, it calls a getter to obtain the Gregorian Day in form of a number (I'm storing the dates in Julian Days); this is, from 0 (sunday) to 6 (saturday), and from that I have a switch that assigns each day in form of a string ("Tuesday") to buffer. It looks like this:

```
void dayWeekStr(DatePtr date,char *buffer)
{
    switch (dayWeek(date))
    {
        case 0:
            buffer="Sunday";
            break;
        case 1:
            buffer="Monday";
            break;
        case 2:
            buffer="Tuesday";
            break;
        case 3:
            buffer="Wednesday";
            break;
        case 4:
            buffer="Thursday";
            break;
        case 5:
            buffer="Friday";
            break;
        case 6:
            buffer="Saturday";
            break;
        default:
            printf("ERROR\n");
            break;
    }
}
```

Back in `main()` you print it and that's it. My main looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    int d=0,m=0,y=0;
    printf("DD MM YYYY: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d",&d,&m,&y);
    printf("\n");
    DatePtr date1=createDate(d,m,y);
    char *s=getDinamicShortDate(date1);
    char *strDay;
    dayWeekStr(date1,strDay);
    printf("Date: %s, %s\n",strDay,s);

    date1=destroyDate(date1);
    free(s);
    s=NULL;
    return 0; 
}
```

So when I run it, I expect this:

```
DD MM AAAA: 9 9 2022
    
Fecha: Friday, 9/9/2022
```

But instead, this is the result:

```
DD MM AAAA: 9 9 2022

Fecha:
```

I really don't know what happened. I tried printing `buffer`'s value inside the function, and it seems it stores it, but then in main it doesn't.

I also tried changing the function to

```
char *dayWeekStr(DatePtr date)
```

so it actually returns a string after the switch:

```
char *dayWeekStr(DatePtr date)
{
    switch (dayWeek(date))
    {
        case 0:
            return "Sunday";
            break;
        case 1:
            return "Monday";
            break;
        case 2:
            return "Tuesday";
            break;
        case 3:
            return "Wednesday";
            break;
        case 4:
            return "Thursday";
            break;
        case 5:
            return "Friday";
            break;
        case 6:
            return "Saturday";
            break;
        default:
            return "-1";
            break;
    }
}
```

In main it only changes from

```
char *strDay;
dayWeekStr(date1,strDay);
```

to

```
char *strDay=dayWeekStr(date1);
```

and it does work. I believe the problem has something to do with the char pointer variable retaining its value after exiting the void function, but **what's the issue here?**

Comment: Your `dayWeekStr()` receives pointer *value*. `buffer=...` modifies *local copy* of the pointer.

Comment: You will get extra marks if you point out to the Prof that "fill in this buffer" functions should take another parameter specifying the maximun size of the buffer (like `fgets( )`...

Comment: You will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers). (hint: answer No)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have passed the *value* of the pointer to your function, which is stored in a local variable. *Assigning* to that local variable does nothing to the original pointer, but if we used string functions which use the value in that pointer, we can. For instance, using [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) to copy the correct string into the buffer pointed to by the function argument.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void weekday(int day, char *buffer) {
  char *days[] = {
    "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
    "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
  };

  if (day <= 6 && day >= 0) {
    strcpy(buffer, days[day]);
  }
  else {
    strcpy(buffer, "-1");
  }
}

int main(void) {
  int day = 2;
  char day_of_week[20] = {0};

  weekday(day, day_of_week);

  printf("%s\n", day_of_week);

  return 0;
}
```

Note also that rather than using a long switch statement or if/else, I've simply indexed into an array of strings. Remember this pattern anytime you are using a switch for a lookup with sequential numbers.

Comment: I asked this to some of my college acquaintances and one actually suggested the same exact thing as you, Chris. Tried this and it works perfectly. Thank you all very much for your answers!